# SmarterGamer.com -- what gives?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange, exact-duplicates

I was doing some research on the ["Shadow Hunters" question asked here](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/656/in-shadow-hunters-can-only-hunters-benefit-from-the-spear-of-longinus) to back up my answer, and managed to stumble up on the exact same question at [SmarterGamer.com](http://smartergamer.com/questions/675/shadows-hunters-do-only-hunters-benefit-from-the-spear-of-longinus).

It looks like a StackExchange site, but it doesn't have any StackExchange information, so is it just a clone site dedicated to all-things-games?  I wonder if there could be any potential confusion between this site and that one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SmarterGamer was started independently as a StackExchange site. However, SmarterGamer was notified a while back that the site would be getting shut down in favor of this site. 
See: http://smartergamer.com/questions/790/site-going-away

Not sure when that will actually happen, though.

Those questions are mine, both here and on SmarterGamer. I was simply transferring over ones that either didn't get answered or didn't have completely satisfactory answers. I was considering transferring others (at least ones I asked). Seems a shame to lose the knowledge if that site goes away.

Comment: interesting, thanks for the clarification.  I figured you were transferring them over, since they didn't have any answers, but I was confused about the existence of the site.

Answer (score 1):

As a follow-up to [Todd's answer](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160/smartergamer-com-what-gives/161#161), it seems to be common practice to merge in SE1 sites (Chip Hacker got merged into [Electronics and Robotics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/), Basically Money got merged into [Personal Finance](https://money.stackexchange.com/), etc.), so assuming that happens here those questions won't be lost, they'll just become part of this site. I'm not sure what that means for reposted questions; we might have to manually close them as duplicates

Comment: Good to know, though it may be difficult in the case of SmarterGamer because we also covered computer games over there, so they couldn't all be copied.

Comment: @Todd Good thing you guys didn't [get rid of board/card games tags](http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/10/how-should-we-tag-questions) over there then ;)

Comment: @Todd When the Gadgets SE2 beta didn't work out, I think the questions got merged to the appropriate other SEs if they existed, such as Apple for Apple or iPhone related questions, Android for Android related, etc.

Comment: I guess as long as things were tagged well, we should be ok then. I wonder when that would likely happen.